# Regular expression to find values starting from beginning and after return

Tags: python, regex

I've got multiple files like this:

```
11111111111111
11010111101101
11110011110101
10014000010001
13500000101111
11108000010161
10100101111501
10000600116051
11011001000101
110080101158001
10012001010001
11111111111111
```

I calculated the number of rows and columns of all of these files. 
Now I'm trying to write some to be sure that all of these files begin with a line full of 1's.

The second one I'm having problems with is to find all those files of which the lengths of all the lines is the number of columns. In this we should not be able to select line 10 with our regular expression.

Comment: Why are you using either `%g` or `%f` there in the first place? `{10.000000}` isn't a valid repeat count. Is that actually the pattern you were trying to create?

Comment: Why the final `\s`? Do those lines end in a space?

Comment: Also, why are you looking for 0 or more copies of 10 1's followed by another 10 1's in the first place? What is that pattern _supposed_ to mean?

Comment: Finally, why are you using `findall` in the first place? If you're trying to check whether the first line is all `1`s, just look at the first line, or get the first match and verify that it starts at position 0, or… just about anything but iterating all of the matches in the file and then trying to figure out how to not see lines after the first after you've already seen them.

Comment: @bakuriu Indeed. All those lines end in a space.

Comment: @abarnet Thanks for your suggestions! You're completely correct. It's better to use another method.

Comment: Does only the first line have to be `1`s or are the `1`s supposed to "frame" the rest of the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find out if the first line contains all 1s, just look at the first line. Reading in the whole file just overcomplicates things. Trying to figure out how many 1s to look for instead of just "all of them" overcomplicates things. Just keep it simple.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    line = next(f, 'X').strip()
    if all(c == '1' for c in line):
        # yes
```

Or, if you want to be a bit clever:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    line = next(f, 'X').strip()
    if not line.replace('1', ''):
        # yes
```

Or, if you really want to use a regular expression:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    line = next(f, 'X').strip()
    if re.match(r'^1+$', line):
        # yes
```

The `next(f, 'X')` makes sure that an empty file doesn't raise an exception, and also fails the test (because `'X'.strip()` isn't made of all 1's), a Jon Clements suggests.

Comment: Okay I was going to go for `if not next(f, 'Z').strip().translate(None, '1')` but... this looks like it's going to be the most comprehensive answer :)

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, but trying to write `str.translate` code that works in both 2.x and 3.x is extra special fun. :)

Comment: Although, now i'm thinking aesthetically `line = next(f, '').strip()` then `if line and not...` but anyway - I'll shut up now :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be the answer to your first problem:

```
^1+\s*\n
```

- `^` beginning of the string
- `1+` the character `1`, repeated at least once
- `\s*` an undefined number of spaces (zero, one or more)
- `\n` end of a line

Comment: You may want to add a space (maybe optional or repeated) before the `\r`, based on the OP's comments.

Comment: Thank you, didn't see that novelty :)

Answer (score 0):

How about we avoid the regular expressions and just read in the file one line at a time?

```
def fileFormatIsCorrect(filename):
    lines = open(filename).readlines()

    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]

        # check for the initial row of ones
        if i == 0 and not (line.strip().replace("1","") == ""):
            return False
        if len(line) != len(lines):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: How about the first line containing only `1`s?